# How can I read an epub book in python

Tags: python, epub

How can I read an `epub` book and open it using python. I'm not able to implement `EbookLib` 0.15 from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/EbookLib/0.15

Here's the code I'm trying

```
from ebooklib import epub 
book = epub.read_epub('test.epub')
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Comment: Have you tried anything in code so far ? Remember stackoverflow will help you resolve code problem, not give you all the code on how to do it.

Comment: i was using 
from ebooklib import epub
book = epub.read_epub('test.epub') and i got the error AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Answer (score 0):

This error was due to a [bug](https://github.com/aerkalov/ebooklib/issues/61) in ebooklib.  The bug was fixed in ebooklib v16.0.

Answer (score -1):

Read the first sentence of
[Read and save does not work](http://docs.sourcefabric.org/projects/ebooklib/en/latest/faq.html#read-and-save-does-not-work) section

> did not put it in a link format because the website is unsecure

I don't think you can read epub files, kinda annoying.

Comment: The commit ref in the site you've linked is 6a004d4a, which dates from 2018 (https://github.com/aerkalov/ebooklib/search?q=6a004d4a&type=commits); I think those docs are out of date.